# Desktop shortcuts and folders don't open unless I open nautilus myself first

Tags: unity

So this isn't really a problem for me, but I am curious as to why this is happening. My guess is that it has something to do with permissions but I am not sure. 
It works exactly as I described. Whenever I log in and click on a desktop shortcut or folder it doesn't open but when I open nautilus myself and just close it then all the desktop shortcuts begin to work as expected for the rest of the session until I log out and in again.

Would appreciate any help as to why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you mount the drive with the desktop apps in fstab?

Comment: No I haven't done any changes to the whole drive mounting procedure, it's all default

Comment: To verify you could manually mount the drive in terminal (without opening Nautilus) and see if your shortcuts work. I had similar behavior and updating fstab with my other drives worked for me.

Comment: Wondering what Ubuntu version you use. Tag indicates Unity as desktop, but are you on 16.04 (comes with Unity as default) or any version higher than 17.10 (comes with Gnome Desktop)?

Comment: The version I'm using is 18.04